# What will be a simple regex for DateTimeGroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I'm trying to make a form with `DTG` (`Date Time Group- 111345ZFEB14`) format and later validate the right input inserted by the users.

for example 
(

> DDHHMMZMYY : 111345ZJuly19 - D: Day, H: Hour, M: Minutes, Z: Zulu, M:
>   Month Y: Year)?

Comment: It's far from perfect, but I guess something like this will do? `^[0-3]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-2]{1}[0-3]{1}[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}Z(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)[0-9]{2}$` - https://regex101.com/r/SPfIRW/1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not master at regex though.

It should work

```
^[0-3]{1}\d{1}[0-2]{1}\d{1}[0-6]\d{1}Z(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\d{2}$
```

For more accurate restriction play with https://regex101.com/r/Wvj2me/2

Comment: Thanks so much Forhad, It worked & sorry for late reply. Could you please explain me.
[0-3]{1}

Comment: [0-3]{1} checks 0, 1, 2, 3 just 1 time. So you are not be able to put something like 6 or 31 at that position.